# Function overriding in native C++

Tags: c++, overriding

Is the following code the correct way to call a base class's overridden function from a derived class's function?:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "BaseClass::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        __super::foo();

        std::cout << "DerivedClass::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    DerivedClass* dc = new DerivedClass();

    dc->foo();

    delete dc;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's another issue. You allocated memory with `new` in `main`, but never deleted it before your program exited. That's not good practice.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - The real issue is that Storm Kiernan called new somewhere other than as the single argument to a smart pointer.

Comment: Yes, that was bad of me.

Comment: Since the poitner as well as allocation of object is for derived type, calling `foo` would always refer to derived function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your call using `__super::foo()` is employing a [Microsoft language extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94dw1w7x.aspx).

Instead you can write `BaseClass::foo()`.

Or if you have a `typedef BaseClass Base`, then `Base::foo()`.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

`BaseClass::foo()`is what you're looking for